# Remove asking what folder and filename to lookup vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have some code that will look up the values from a different file.

I've already included the path and filename, but it always asks what file will I look up.

Here's my code:

```
Filename = "C:\data\accounts"    
ActiveSheet.Range("W:W").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=INDEX('" & Filename & "[Accounts.xlsx]Accounts'!C6,MATCH(C2,'" & Filename & "[Accounts.xlsx]Accounts'!C3,0))"
```

Do I need to add `application.screenupdating`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the  "C:\data\accounts"   needs to include a terminating \ in the string.

Use

> Filename = "C:\data\accounts\"